# Problems with dynamic height in Windows Phone 8 (see sketch inside)

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8

I'm currently fiddling with a Windows Phone 8 Gui but i have run into some problems. The idea is rather simple:

There's a scrollviewer in the App that has 3 items in it. One of them (A) is always visible and has a fixed height. The two others (B and C) are supposed to have a dynamic height that uses the rest of the available screenspace in the scrollviewer (see sketch)

[image: Sketch of the GUI]

I have not been able to either

1) Find a XAML definitions that allows me to set-up the layout in the described way. The main Problem is getting the content in the scrollviewer to automatically have the correct height for the scrolling to happen and everything to line up exactly.

or

2) Dynamically set the correct height for all items in the code behind. My main problem here is getting the heights of the dynamically sized objects. Whatever i try i either get 0,0 or 0 or NaN.

here is the XAML code i have so far

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
        x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
        SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="224"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,108">
                <TextBlock x:Name="subtitle" Text="Help Me" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="title" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}">
                    <Run Text="StackOverflow"/>
                    <Run Text="!"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>


            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,136,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="mainScrollViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="633" Margin="0">
                    <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!--Here are my Elements A, B, C -->
                        <Image x:Name="element_B" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Assets/b5xhG.png"/>
                        <Image x:Name="element_A" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Assets/b5xhG.png"/>
                        <Image x:Name="element_C" Grid.Row="2" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Assets/b5xhG.png"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

and here's my minimal code behind

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
    using PhoneApp1.Resources;

    namespace PhoneApp1
    {
        public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
            // Konstruktor
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                /*when the app starts, the height of the ContentGrid should be equal to the height of the Scrollviewer,
                 * therefore the height that element A and B should be together*/
                var BAndCHeight = contentGrid.Height - element_A.Height;

                /*with that in mind, the new height of the Content in the Scrollviewer should be */
                var contentGridSupposedHeight = 2 * BAndCHeight + element_A.Height;

            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone give me a hint how this is supposed to be done? Maybe I'm missing something. If not, how do i get the correct heights of the Elements so i can scale them myself?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try giving a height to your Grid which contains your scroll viewer.

Comment: Giving it a fixed height does work (aka returns that set height) however since this is the part of my UI that does the Scaling i can't have it at a fixed height since it's height changes when going from a 800x480 to a 1280x720 Device. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: if height given in % then the resolution issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try ActualHeight instead of Height.
This Should give the current height of the elements.

```
var BAndCHeight = contentGrid.ActualHeight - element_A.ActualHeight;
```

This may only be used during or after the Loaded event because the elements are actually rendered during the Loaded event.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly i tried every combination of height/Actual Height etc. It always yields 0,0; 0 or NaN (see this screenshot for example http://i.imgur.com/tC9Bh9G.png)

Comment: I just noticed that the contentGrid Height is not specified.
It might work if you also change contentGrid.Height to contentGrid.ActualHeight.

Comment: Have you tried to check the Height of both element separately? It is possible that the contentGrid and element_A has the same height.

And also, you can only get the ActualHeight property after the Loaded event or other similar event. I hope this helps.

Comment: i had thought of that but it's not the case visually. Here is an overview of all the Heights involved

http://i.imgur.com/f68khZb.png

As you can see scrollViewerHeight is the only usable one (thanks for that though it's a first step) the rest is not usable

Comment: Have you already tried to check those Height and ActualHeight values during the Loaded event?
I guess those values will change since the elements were actually rendered.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think no need to set dynamically height of any element, Your issue should be resolved  in your xaml. May this will help you, You can copy paste xaml. 

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
        x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
        SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" >
                <TextBlock x:Name="subtitle" Text="Help Me" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="title" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}">
                    <Run Text="StackOverflow"/>
                    <Run Text="!"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>


            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row0="1">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="mainScrollViewer"  Margin="0">
                    <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!--Here are my Elements A, B, C -->
                        <Image x:Name="element_B" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Assets/b5xhG.png"/>
                        <Image x:Name="element_A" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Assets/b5xhG.png"/>
                        <Image x:Name="element_C" Grid.Row="2" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Assets/b5xhG.png"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't work as described. The problem with your solution can be seen here: 

http://i.imgur.com/e3kQNkA.png

Left side is your idea, Right side is waht i want to happen

Answer (score 0):

To get the sizes right in the contentGrid, try this:

Set all your row heights to "Auto" in XAML

Then in your Loaded event handler, find which row has the largest ActualHeight and then set the heights of the other two rows to size "*"

```
    void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double h = -1;

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            if (contentGrid.RowDefinitions[row].ActualHeight > h)
                h = contentGrid.RowDefinitions[row].ActualHeight;

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            if (contentGrid.RowDefinitions[row].ActualHeight < h)
                contentGrid.RowDefinitions[row].Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
```

contentGrid.RowDefinitions[tallestRow].Height = System.Windows.GridLength.Auto;
}